# Linux command (unzip -p) run with exec-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, command-line, maven-3, unzip, exec-maven-plugin

I have **my.zip** file under project’s `target/` folder.

```
MyProject/
    -target/
           -my.zip
     -pom.xml
```

Inside **my.zip** there is a file named *names.txt*. If I run linux command under project root:

```
unzip -p target/my.zip names.txt > target/names.txt
```

I successfully get the *names.txt* extracted to `target/` folder:

```
MyProject/
    -target/
           -my.zip
           -names.txt
     -pom.xml
```

I want to execute the same command with [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) defined in **pom.xml**.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>get names.txt</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>exec</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <!-- define the command to execute -->
             <executable>unzip</executable>
             <arguments>
               <commandlineArgs>-p target/my.zip names.txt > target/names.txt</commandlineArgs>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
```

But when I run `maven clean install`, it doesn’t generate the *names.txt* , the terminal shows me unzip help document instead:

```
UnZip 5.52 of 28 February 2005, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

  -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
  -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive
```

why? How can I make it working with exec-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` isn't a valid option for `unzip`. `>` or stdout redirection is a feature of the shell which you use to execute the command. That means the shell will see `>`, strip it and the next argument, create a new process for `unzip`, redirect stdout of the new process and start it.

`exec-maven-plugin` doesn't use a shell; instead it's using the same API which the shell uses internally to create new processes. That means `unzip` will start, find strange options from the command line and quit with an error.

To fix this, run the `executable` `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` with

```
<commandlineArgs>-c "unzip -p target/my.zip names.txt &gt; target/names.txt"</commandlineArgs>
```

Note that you really should HTML escape `>`.

To avoid all these problems, you can either put these commands into a shell script and execute that or use [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and [the `unzip` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html).

Comment: Tried with `&gt;` instead of `>`, it doesn't work either

Comment: @user842225: That's not the only thing that you need to change.

Comment: @ Aaron , I nonticed that you updated your answer by adding `-c unzip` , but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I use Maven AntRun plugin resolved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: you have to quote your command. <commandlineArgs>-c "unzip -p target/my.zip names.txt > target/names.txt"</commandlineArgs>

Comment: @Corentin Good catch. Yeah, `bash -c` expects a single argument (the command to execute).

Answer (score 3):

The [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) has an option `outputFile` which writes the output of a command into the appropriate file.